# Enonic-xp cms localhost data fetch issue react native

Tags: react-native, axios, graphql, content-management-system

I deploy enonic-xp cms in my localhost.I want to fetch data using graphql. But it doesn't work. we deploy enonic-xp in localhost, they provide the below URL with guillotine playground.

> http://localhost:8080/site/hmdb/master/hmdb/api

when I tried in below graphql code in the playground area, it works well & I can see the result. But when I try in axios it will generate possible unhandled promise rejection. I try to get a response in the console log.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View,Button} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';


const endpoint = 'http://localhost:8080/site/hmdb/master/hmdb/api';
const GRAPHQL_QUERY = `
{
  guillotine {
    query(query: "type='testproject:movie'", first: 1) {
      displayName
      data : dataAsJson
      }
  }
}
`;

const Home = () => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    await axios({
      url: endpoint,
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        query: GRAPHQL_QUERY,
      },
      headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",     
      }
    }).then(response => console.log(response));
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
        <View>
          <Button title="get Data" onPress={fetchData} />
        </View>

)}
export default Home;
```

error

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
Error: Network Error
createError@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.graphql&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:111045:26
handleError@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.graphql&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:110831:69
dispatchEvent@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.graphql&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:31287:31
setReadyState@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.graphql&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:30402:33
__didCompleteResponse@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.graphql&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:30208:29
emit@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.graphql&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2090:42
__callFunction@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.graphql&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:3056:36
http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.graphql&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2780:31
__guard@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.graphql&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:3007:15
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.graphql&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2779:21
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should to wrap `GRAPHQL_QUERY` using `JSON.stringify`.
GraphQL request body:

```
{
   query: "",
   variables: "", // optional
   operationName: "" // optional
}
```